# Custom Module: db_select title AND body?

Tags: database

I'm a little confused by how the node data is stored in the database.  It seems like the title is stored in the db "node," while the body is stashed field_data_body, and custom fields are placed elsewhere.

I have create a custom module that pulls certain pieces of content, but I need to match up the title with the body.  I've been successful pulling my list of titles:

```
    function foo() {
      $query = db_select('node', 'n')
       ->fields('n', array('type','title', 'nid'))
       ->condition('type', 'fooBar')
       ->condition('status',1)
       ->execute();
          return $query;
      }
      $result=foo();
        foreach ($result as $node) {
         $id = $node->nid;
        }
```

How can I match each of these with their bodies?

Thanks!
-JB

Answer (score 1):

If you want directly include the body within your result set, you can do a join on the `field_data_body` table.

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');

$query->leftJoin('field_data_body', 'd', '(d.entity_id = n.nid AND d.entity_type = :node)', array(':node' => 'node'));

$query
    ->fields('n', array('type', 'title', 'nid'))
    ->fields('d', array('body_value', 'body_summary', 'body_format'))
    ->condition('type', 'fooBar')
    ->condition('status', 1)
    ->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct - Drupal stores the data for fields inside of separate tables.
Depending on your use case, you may find it easier to use node_load() which will load the entire node object with all the field data.